# Problem with user logins after db Restore

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two SQL 2005 instances that reside on different networks. I need to backup a database from instance A and restore it to a database in instance B on a weekly basis so that both databases hold the same data.  After the restore, logins SIDS on database B are changed and therefore users can't log into database B and connection strings for the web application it supports are broken. Is there a work around for this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a stored procedure for that: `sp_change_users_login` (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174378.aspx).  In particular, take a look at the `Auto_Fix` action.  However, be aware that this SP is going to be deprecated in the future.

Insead, we're now supposed to use `ALTER USER` (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176060.aspx).

Comment: This was the fix: alter user [username] with login = [username];